# Why does the given code throw a heap corruption error?

Tags: c, string, heap-corruption

The following code throws a heap corruption when it tries to free lpSubKey.

What exactly is going wrong?

```
#define DRIVER_NAME L"TEST"
#define SUB_KEY     L"System\\CurrentControlSet\\Services\\"

size_t len = (wcslen(SUB_KEY) + wcslen(DRIVER_NAME) + 1) * sizeof(WCHAR);
LPWSTR lpSubKey = calloc(1, len);

wcscat_s(lpSubKey, len, SUB_KEY);
wcscat_s(lpSubKey, len, DRIVER_NAME);

free(lpSubKey);
```

EDIT: The error is thrown even when this is the only code in main() so the error isn't occurring elsewhere.

EDIT2: Updating the code to reflect the accepted answer has solved the problem. I still don't see why there was an error in the first place. Even if wcscat_s wasn't providing protection because len wasn't the correct value, my buffer should have been large enough to hold both strings.

```
#define DRIVER_NAME L"TEST"
#define SUB_KEY     L"System\\CurrentControlSet\\Services\\"

size_t len = wcslen(SUB_KEY) + wcslen(DRIVER_NAME) + 1;
LPWSTR lpSubKey = calloc(len, sizeof(WCHAR));

wcscat_s(lpSubKey, len, SUB_KEY);
wcscat_s(lpSubKey, len, DRIVER_NAME);

free(lpSubKey);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no evidence here of any particular error (the string you allocate is big enough), so the problem probably lies elsewhere.

However, remember that `wcscat_s` requires the *number of elements*, not the size of the buffer, so the `_s` versions of the C functions here aren't protecting you in any way. A more coherent way of working (where `len` contains the *number of characters*, not of bytes) may be:

```
size_t len = (wcslen(SUB_KEY) + wcslen(DRIVER_NAME) + 1);
LPWSTR lpSubKey = calloc(len, sizeof(WCHAR));

wcscat_s(lpSubKey, len, SUB_KEY);
wcscat_s(lpSubKey, len, DRIVER_NAME);

free(lpSubKey);
```

***Update***

Given that fixing this has fixed the problem, I suspect that `wcscat_s` always intentionally NUL-terminates the buffer at the `len` character, both to make sure that the buffer is always NUL-terminated, and to make potential bugs like these evident.